# Insert Picture in PowerPoint from Folder based on Cell Value from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, image, powerpoint

The goal is to insert pictures in a table in a PowerPoint from a folder based on values in Excel.

I have five pictures (.png) located in a folder on my device.
The cell values in Excel goes from 1 to 5.

Depending on the cell value, I would like one of the pictures to be inserted in a table in PowerPoint.

E.g.: If Excel value = 2 then insert picture2 in PowerPoint table.

```vb
Sub ESG_Globes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Define PPT objects
Dim oPPT            As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim appPPT          As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oWS             As Excel.Worksheet
Dim fileNameString  As String
Dim boolUploadToIntranet As Boolean
Dim cells As Range
Dim s14 As Integer, s15 As Integer, s13 As Integer
Dim ESG1, ESG2, ESG3, ESG4, ESG5 As String
Dim ImageBox, ImageBox2 As PowerPoint.Shape

With oPPT.Slides(8)
    For k = 4 To 22
        'Globes PNG Location
        ESG1 = "S:\S8RENTE\Credit & Equity Research\ESG\Grafik\Glober (PNG)\SustainabilityRating_Low.png"
        ESG2 = "S:\S8RENTE\Credit & Equity Research\ESG\Grafik\Glober (PNG)\SustainabilityRating_BelowAverage.png"
        ESG3 = "S:\S8RENTE\Credit & Equity Research\ESG\Grafik\Glober (PNG)\SustainabilityRating_Average.png"
        ESG4 = "S:\S8RENTE\Credit & Equity Research\ESG\Grafik\Glober (PNG)\SustainabilityRating_AboveAverage.png"
        ESG5 = "S:\S8RENTE\Credit & Equity Research\ESG\Grafik\Glober (PNG)\SustainabilityRating_High.png"
    
        ' Check if file is open - if not, open it
        fOpen = IsFileOpen("S:\S8RENTE\Aktieanalyse\Vaerktoejer\Aktieoverblik\Aktieoverblik - Sektoropdeling\Aktieoverblik_PPT - Sektor.pptx")
        If Not fOpen Then
            Set appPPT = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
            Set oPPT = appPPT.Presentations.Open("S:\S8RENTE\Aktieanalyse\Vaerktoejer\Aktieoverblik\Aktieoverblik - Sektoropdeling\Aktieoverblik_PPT - Sektor.pptx")
        Else
            Set appPPT = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
            Set oPPT = appPPT.Presentations("Udkast til Aktieoverblik.pptx")
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PPT DATA")
        Set owb = ActiveWorkbook
                
        If oWS.cells(k, 37) = "1" Then
            Set wdPic = .Cell(k, 37).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename:=ESG1, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        If oWS.cells(k, 37) = "2" Then
            Set wdPic = .Cell(k, 37).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename:=ESG2, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        If oWS.cells(k, 37) = "3" Then
            Set wdPic = .Cell(k, 37).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename:=ESG3, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        If oWS.cells(k, 37) = "4" Then
            Set wdPic = .Cell(k, 37).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename:=ESG4, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        If oWS.cells(k, 37) = "5" Then
            Set wdPic = .Cell(k, 37).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename:=ESG5, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

        End If
        wdPic.Height = 0.3 * 28.34646
        wdPic.Width = 0.3 * 28.34646
        Set wdPic2 = wdPic.ConvertToShape
        wdPic2.Left = CentimetersToPoints(4 - (y * 0.3))
        y = y + 1

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code appears to be inserting/trying to insert pictures into cells in a worksheet, not in a PowerPoint table.  But that aside, you can't insert pictures into cells in PowerPoint tables, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1
For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
            i = i + 1
        fName = Dir
    Loop
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


' Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.
Sub Insert()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range
    strFolder = "C:\Pictures\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If
    Set rngCell = Range("E1") 'starting cell
    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.jpg", vbNormal) 'filter for .png files
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One small glitch: PowerPoint tables can't hold graphics, just text. You can position your pictures in a grid by using their Top and Left properties, but using a table for positioning them will not work.

You can use a picture to fill a cell as a background, but the cell dimensions must match the picture's to avoid distortion. To do this, use a statement like:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Filepath\Filename")
```